# Silently Updating Firefox via Command Prompt (Windows)

Tags: batch-file, firefox, updates

I have a batch file which silently installs *Firefox* and this works fine. (I add `-ms` to the line where I execute the installation file.)

Now I want to update Firefox in the same batch file only if it's not the newest Version. The version test is already in the batch file and is working fine.

**And now my Question is:** How can I silently update Firefox?

I already tried the steps from this [link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:Manually_Installing_a_MAR_file) but they are not working, no errors just doing nothing. Is there maybe another possibility?

**Edit:**

This is the code of my batch file.
The line `if %errorlevel%==1 %INSTALLDIR%\Mozilla Firefox\updater.exe -ms` needs to be replaced with the silent update for *Firefox* (which is hopefully working).

```
@echo off

IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==x86 SET INSTALLDIR=%ProgramFiles%
IF %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%==AMD64 SET INSTALLDIR=%ProgramFiles(x86)%

IF NOT EXIST "%INSTALLDIR%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" goto install

REM Update Firefox if the Version is not 37.0
:update
CD %INSTALLDIR%\Mozilla Firefox\
firefox -v | more | find /i "37"
if %errorlevel%==0 goto end
if %errorlevel%==1 %INSTALLDIR%\Mozilla Firefox\updater.exe -ms
goto end

REM Install Firefox if it's not installed yet
:install
\\***\***\Firefox-Setup-37.exe -ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest for this task the following commented batch code:

```
@echo off
set "FirefoxFolder="
set "FirefoxVersion=37"

rem Get path of installed Firefox directly from Windows registry.
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe" /v Path 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%I" == "Path" (
        set "FirefoxFolder=%%K"
        if defined FirefoxFolder goto CheckFirefox
    )
)

:InstallFirefox
echo Installing Firefox ...

:UpdateFireFox
\\***\***\Firefox-Setup-%FirefoxVersion%.exe -ms
goto :EOF

:CheckFirefox
if not exist "%FirefoxFolder%\firefox.exe" goto InstallFirefox

rem Check if version of Mozilla Firefox starts with defined number.
rem The space at beginning makes sure to find the major version number.
"%FirefoxFolder%\firefox.exe" -v | %SystemRoot%\System32\more | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe " %FirefoxVersion%" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Updating Firefox to version %FirefoxVersion% ...
    goto UpdateFireFox
)

echo Firefox with version %FirefoxVersion% is already installed.
```

The path to *Firefox* executable is read directly from Windows registry. This should work on any Windows, even on Windows XP.

I have read that for updating *Firefox* just the installer must be executed. The installer automatically detects an already installed version of *Firefox* and updates it without changing the user settings.

Comment: Thanks I kinda combined our two codes and now everything is working as I wanted it. Thanks for leading me to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

I liked Mofi's code so much I went ahead and transformed it into a fully unattended installer, using curl and powershell. Thank you Mofi! Run this code and you will have the latest firefox version whether firefox is already installed or not!

```
@echo off
set "FirefoxFolder="
Title Firefox Updater
curl --silent -o "%TEMP%\firefoxdl.txt" "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=win64&lang=en-US"
powershell -command "(Get-Content "%TEMP%\firefoxdl.txt") | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '^.*releases.([0-9][0-9]).*$','$1' } | Set-Content "%TEMP%\firefoxdl.txt""
set /p FirefoxVersion=<"%TEMP%\firefoxdl.txt"
del "%TEMP%\firefoxdl.txt"
Echo The Latest Release of Firefox is version %FirefoxVersion%.

rem Get path of installed Firefox directly from Windows registry.
for /F "skip=2 tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe" /v Path 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%A" == "Path" (
        set "FirefoxFolder=%%C"
        if defined FirefoxFolder goto CheckFirefox
    )
)

:InstallFirefox

:UpdateFireFox
Echo Downloading Firefox Version %FirefoxVersion%...
curl --silent -L -o "%TEMP%\firefoxcurrent.exe" "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=win64&lang=en-US"
Echo Installing Firefox Version %FirefoxVersion%, please wait...
tasklist /fi "imagename eq firefox.exe" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "firefox.exe" >nul 2>&1
start "" /wait "%TEMP%\firefoxcurrent.exe" -ms
Echo Cleaning Up!
del "%TEMP%\firefoxcurrent.exe"
goto :EOF

:CheckFirefox
if not exist "%FirefoxFolder%\firefox.exe" goto InstallFirefox

rem Check if version of Mozilla Firefox starts with defined number.
rem The space at beginning makes sure to find the major version number.
"%FirefoxFolder%\firefox.exe" -v | %SystemRoot%\System32\more | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe " %FirefoxVersion%" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Updating Firefox to version %FirefoxVersion% ...
    goto UpdateFireFox
)

echo However, Firefox version %FirefoxVersion% is already installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Chocolately:

```
choco upgrade firefox -y
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).