# How to run an .exe file stored in a variable?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a little batch file in order to silently install Firefox.

I would like to store the executable file name into a variable (SETUP_64 or SETUP_32). This would allow me to change the file version without edditing the script.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set SETUP_64="Firefox-*-64.exe"
set SETUP_32="Firefox-*-32.exe"

if %processor_architecture% == AMD64 (
  start %SETUP_64%

) else (
  start %SETUP_32%
)


Echo DONE

PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
```

Problem is that the script is not working properly. Can anyone help me find the solution?

Is there another command than `start %variable%`? Maybe my variable is wrong?

Executable files are stored at the same place as my script `install.bat`.

Comment: The `START` command treats the first quoted argument as the Window Title. So you need an empty set of quotes. `start "" %SETUP_64%`. Best practice is to NOT assign quotes to variables but do you use them to protect special characters and from trailing spaces being assigned to a variable. `set "SETUP_64=Firefox-*-64.exe"`

Comment: @Squashman Thank you very much for your answer. It's seems to be working. The only problem is that my script as trouble to find "Firefox-*-64.exe". But  it's working if I put the full name inside the variable (without *). Any idea?

Comment: @Compo Does it mean that I have to rename my file `Firefox-*-AMD64.exe` ? What is `:~-2`

Comment: No, `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%` holds only the last two characters of `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the asterisk in your code. I just saw the obvious problems with your code.  Why do you not know the complete file name?

Comment: Don't use the environment variable `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`. It's value is `x86` when the batch file is executed by 32 bit `cmd.exe` because of application started the batch file is also a 32 bit application as documented by Microsoft in article about [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/wow64-implementation-details). I recommend something like `if "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" (set "FireFoxArchitecture=32") else set "FireFoxArchitecture=64"`. Double click on  `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` and run `set proc` and you see that I'm right.

Comment: And please first verify if Firefox is not already installed before installing Firefox and also its version before installing an older version over an already installed newer version. See for example [Silently Updating Firefox via Command Prompt (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29768157/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea for performing the task, which assumes that you're happy to run the executable regardless of whether an existing version of `Firefox` is already installed or not.

```bat
@Echo Off
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
    Start "" /D "%__CD__%" "%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe" /C "%~f0"&Exit /B)
If %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2% Equ 86 (Call :Sub 32)Else Call :Sub 64
Pause
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
For %%A In ("%~dp0Firefox-*-%1.exe")Do (Start "" /Wait "%%A"
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 Echo Done)
Exit /B
```

This works by ensuring that the appropriate version of `cmd.exe` is running the batch file first. *This is necessary because if the 32-bit version of `cmd.exe` is running the script on a `x64` system, the `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` variable value will be `x86`. However when the 32-bit version of `cmd.exe` is running on a `x64` system, a new environment variable `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432%` is defined, which does not exist in 64-bit `cmd.exe` on a `x64` system, or 32-bit `cmd.exe` on a `x86` system.* Once the script is running in the correct bitness version of `cmd.exe`, we can rely on the output of `%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%` for running the appropriate executable.

As an additional comment, the Firefox executables, *which are essentially just self-extracting 7z archives*, appear to have exactly the same name, regardless of which bitness version you download, e.g. `Firefox Setup 66.0.2.exe`. This means that the executables in the question must have been been renamed, and so you could rename them to anything at all you want. If you use the same renaming scheme, but instead use `-86` instead of `-32` you could simplify the code a little too:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Defined PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 (
    Start "" /D "%__CD__%" "%SystemRoot%\SysNative\cmd.exe" /C "%~f0"&Exit /B)
For %%A In ("%~dp0Firefox-*-%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:~-2%.exe")Do (
    Start "" /Wait "%%A"
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 Echo Done
    Pause)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will try to understand and use this script.

Answer (score 0):

I moved a quote, and I added the silent install flag.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set "SETUP_64=Firefox*64.exe"
set "SETUP_32=Firefox*32.exe" 

if %processor_architecture% == AMD64 (
  start %SETUP_64% -ms

) else (
  start %SETUP_32% -ms
)


Echo DONE

PAUSE
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Sadly the problem is still the same, "Can't find Firefox*64.exe".